# CrudRepository: Save method deletes entry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Calling `CrudRepository.save()` method deletes entry instead of updating the existing entry.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = PATCH)   
public User update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody UpdateUser existingUser) {
  return userService.update(existingUser);
}
```

Service:

```
public User update(UpdateUser existingUser) {
  if (!userRepository.exists(existingUser.getId()) {
    throw new UserNotFoundException();
  }

  UserEntity userEntity = existingUser.toEntity();
  return userRepository.save(userEntity).toDto();
}
```

Dtos:

```
public User {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  // ..

  public UserEntity toEntity() {
    UserEntity entity = new UserEntity();
    entity.setId(id);
    entity.setName(name);
    return entity;
  }
}

public UpdateUser extends User {
  @NotNull
  @Override
  public Long getId() {
    super.getId();
  }
}
```

I made sure that ID is set on the Dto as it's recieved by the controller & the service and that it's still the same after update. In any case what happens is that service `update` method appears to save & delete the entity. Because I get back the dto which would have been created from entity returned from `save` method and I can see the changed name. However if I refresh the page or look into the `users` table the entry is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're always creating a new Entity and saving it (in your toEntity() method, which essentially overwrites the previous entity.

If you want to update an existing User, you need to do **fetch + update** on it's fields, and then invoke save.

for example this will update the name of an existing user:

```
UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findOneById(existingUser.getId())
userEntity.setName(newName);
userRepository.save(userEntity);
```

You should also not set the ID of the entities by hand. Leverage @Id
and @GeneratedValue.

Comment: A ok that makes sense I need to find a more elegant way of converting between DTOs and Entities.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this post here helped me.
Instead of constructing a new entity with the builder pattern.

```
MovieEntity movieEntity = MovieEntity.builder()
    .id(uuid)
    .scene(movie.getScene())
    .imageUrl(movieEntityOptional.get().getImageUrl())
    .build();
```

I had to reuse and save the same one I got from repository.findById() as in

```
MovieEntity movieEntity = movieEntityOptional.get();
movieEntity.setId(uuid);
movieEntity.setScene(movie.getScene());
movieEntity.setImageUrl(movieEntityOptional.get().getImageUrl());
```